# IIS HTTP Error 400 (Invalid Verb) -- corrupted request?

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome, iis

Looking for some help on this one. I'm somewhat limited on what I can share since the app is internal...

Scenario: Web app makes a POST request to /api/shortLink endpoint to get back a short link (think: URL shortening service) to a dashboard within our BI application. The shortlink saves parameter/filter values so the user can return to the same view using the short link.

The shortLink service returns a regular 200 status and the shortLink code. All is well, right? Not so.. The very next HTTP request (GET, POST, doesn't matter) from the page results in an HTTP 400 error (Invalid Verb).

The issue is only happening in Chrome (latest build).
Firefox, IE11, Vivaldi and Safari all work fine.

Initial post request to get a shortLink value (works fine, shortLink is generated and returned:

```
Request: 
POST http://jaxbamaptst1:8000/api/shortlink/?sessionId=4ea65890-dbb2-4757-8f03-c0e3bf306cdf HTTP/1.1
Host: jaxbamaptst1:8000
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 18192
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Accept: */*
Origin: http://jaxbamaptst1:8000
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Referer: http://jaxbamaptst1:8000/Dashboard/1e4ce64e-31e7-4f9e-96aa-8b9e546ba5c8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: webapp_sessionid=4ea65890-dbb2-4757-8f03-c0e3bf306cdf; webapp_clientid=27271080-59a9-4c3c-aaef-d8c489414165

"/Dashboard/41c892a0-d83c-4d98-beaa-cee8c656c727?e=false&vo=viewonly&overrides=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<<snip rest of overrides. Very lengthy>>
```

The response is also normal and returns the desired shortLink:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-store, must-revalidate, no-cache, max-age=0
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: Mon, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Date: Fri, 30 Sep 2016 02:44:21 GMT
Content-Length: 28

"saqecfh3x14wmygknpqnzxwt3w"
```

Now, no matter what the next call is from the page, the result will be an HTTP 400 - Invalid Verb

The request looks completely normal in Chrome. However, when you look at it in Fiddler, things get a little odd..

Here's a failing request:

```
JSZVVUAXF1ZU5HBWUIOIJBRGLTIEVTCGXVEWVLXS5BQ3VYCMVUDCBPCMCTQ2VUDGVYLVVNLVRNLUFNZW50XS5BT3JNYW5PEMF0AW9UXS4MW1JDJLTDTUNDIIWIAGLLCMFYY2H5VW5PCXVLTMFTZSI6ILTEAW0GRW1WBG95ZWVDLLTDDXJYZW50IE9YZY1DZW50ZXITVU0TVE0TQWDLBNRDIIWIY2FWDGLVBII6IKNNQYISIMXLDMVSV<<snipped for brevity>>SBGFWC2VKIJPMYWXZZSWIY2HPBGRJDGVTQ291BNQIOJASINVUAXF1ZU5HBWUIOIJBRGLTIGET http://jaxbamaptst1:8000/Link/?shortLink=saqecfh3x14wmygknpqnzxwt3w HTTP/1.1
Host: jaxbamaptst1:8000
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Referer: http://jaxbamaptst1:8000/Dashboard/1e4ce64e-31e7-4f9e-96aa-8b9e546ba5c8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: webapp_sessionid=4ea65890-dbb2-4757-8f03-c0e3bf306cdf;      webapp_clientid=27271080-59a9-4c3c-aaef-d8c489414165
```

Note the encoded data (or garbled nothingness?) preceding the "GET" verb. Not surprising that IIS is returning the error 400.

Chrome looks like all was well (except for the 400 response):

```
Request URL:http://jaxbamaptst1:8000/Link/?shortLink=saqecfh3x14wmygknpqnzxwt3w
Request Method:GET
Status Code:400 Bad Request
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:8888  <<due to Fiddler proxy>>
```

Ever seen anything like this?

Also, as an aside -- We don't usually use SSL with this app since it is internal. However, I noticed that if I access it using SSL the error does not occur.

Comment: Looks like the second request tries to GET and NOT to POST the request to the API. Normally the endpoint will reject (for security reasons) any GET request.

Comment: Thanks Franco. GET is expected here. It is not an API endpoint. It is an attempt to navigate to the shortlink page.

Answer (score 3):

Resolved: Finally figured out this morning that this issue was caused by McAfee DLP. Leaving this here in case anyone else runs into a similar situation.

Comment: Under what circumstances does McAfee's DLP do this?

Comment: I wish I knew exactly what aspect of these requests caused the issue. After we determined DLP was the source of the issue, we sent similar information as to what I posted above to McAfee. All we got back was a note with the next release of essentially "try it now."